# If the GCM server receives a message to be sent to an Android phone, is the message going to survive on the server until it reaches the client?

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

I mean, once the message has reached the server, can I rely on GCM for that message to arrive to the phone whenever the phone is online? Can the message be lost in the middle of the way to the phone? Is there a confirmation (message arrvied) between server and phone?

I read in the documentation that "GCM makes no guarantees about delivery or the order of messages" but I don't understand if this means that the message can be lost while trying to reach the phone or that if the phone is off the message will never arrive to the phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the phone is off and you turn it on you will then get the GCM message, its the same as you would an email that you got if you had your phone off. When it says there is no guarantee you will receive the message that means there is no guarantee the server will send it out. I remember reading there is a `time to live` on the message but its not one that expires for a while

Comment: So are you saying that the server may decide not to send a message (remove it from the system, expire it...)?

Comment: correct, that is why you should never rely/expect on the message to be received